# How to fade a line out in photoshop

Tags: photoshop-effects

I have 1 RGB layer; the background. Its background is white. There is a solid line on this image. I wish to fade its left end out to white. How can I do this please?

Answer (score 10):

1. Make sure your line is on it's own layer.
2. "Add Layer Mask" to the layer
3. Select the gradient tool, make sure it fades from black to white
4. Click and drag the gradient on the layer mask

This will fade the line to whatever is behind it, as it makes it transparent.

Comment: This is a more powerful option as it gives you the ability to change the background colour at a later time without having to redo anything else

Comment: Oh, what the heck, +1. But my method's good for programs with no [native] support for masks (not mentioning any names, *Paint.NET*, ahem).

Answer (score 3):

If you are drawing the line, use the gradient tool, and make your right end the color and the left end white.

If you are editing someone else's work, try this:

- Use the Selection tool and draw a
  marquee around the part you want to
  fade.
- Go into Quick Mask. It should be on Mask is Selected Area.
- Select the Gradient tool.
- Draw gradients until you like how it
  fades. That is, until you like how the gradient of the Quick Mask color covers your line.
- Exit Quick Mask.
- Layer → Layer Mask → Hide
  Selection.

If you don't like how it looks, back up in your History to the Quick Mask step and repeat as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Quickly, young hero:

- Create a new layer
- Draw a line
- Select the area around it (the "background")
- Invert Selection
- Select your gradient tool
- Make the primary color the color you want, and the secondary color entirely transparent (Alpha?)
- Delete the contents of your selection (delete key?), and draw the gradient from one corner to the other corner of the line
- Merge layer into your main layer (or leave it alone, if you want)

May your sword stay sharp!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a rub of the eraser with a 0 hardness.

Answer (score 0):

Ways:

1. Layer mask. (Then i merge it cause i dont want huge layers to be hanging out)
2. Rasterize>HugeSoftFadingBrushEraser.
3. Gradient Layer effect//clippingLayer.